# E: Unable to locate package python3-boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, boto3

I  want to install python3-boto3 with code sudo apt-get install python3-boto3 and I get error E: Unable to locate package python3-boto3
what should I do? I used ubuntu 14.04 lts

Comment: Have you updated the package repositories? if not, refer the following link, https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/python-boto3

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
python3 -m pip install boto3
```

Answer (score 1):

I launched an Ubuntu 14.04 instance and managed to **install boto3** as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sudo pip3 install boto3
```

Then when you use it, you have to use `python3`, instead of `python`.

Comment: This is for my curiosity : Why doesn't pip3 search boto3 return favorable results?

Comment: @RoshinRaphel I tried the search now and I get plenty of boto3 type results.

Comment: Yes, but aren't they like `boto3-stubs`, `boto3-type` etc, not the  exact ones?

Comment: @RoshinRaphel I see. Not sure. Maybe because its already installed?

Comment: I was not the one who posted the question, but done the up voting.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel Ah, I see. Thanks and also your command would also work, after installing python3.

Comment: @Marcin after update I get error : E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

what should i do?

Comment: Can you spin up new instance. Maybe it already got corrupted by some earlier attempts of install.